# How to display all the questions by level of difficulty

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable and I want to display the questions according to their level of difficulty , the program executes normally but the problem is that it displays only one difficulty level (Difficult questions) I want to view all the questions by their level of difficulty ? I need to sum all the IF on the JTable ? Or i have a problem on IF ?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            categorie=GestionCategorieDelegate.doFindCategorieById(PreparerTest.idCategorie);
            System.out.println(categorie);
            if(Facile.getText().length()!=0)
            {
                questions=GestionTestDelegate.doPrepareRandomTest(Integer.parseInt(Facile.getText()), categorie,"Facile");

            } 
            else
            {

            }
            if(Moyen.getText().length()!=0)
            {
                questions=GestionTestDelegate.doPrepareRandomTest(Integer.parseInt(Moyen.getText()), categorie, "Moyen");

            }
            else
            {

            }
            if(Difficile.getText().length()!=0)
            {
                questions=GestionTestDelegate.doPrepareRandomTest(Integer.parseInt(Difficile.getText()), categorie, "Difficile");

            }
            System.out.println(questions);
            initDataBindings();
        }
```

this the result
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that on each of your if blocks, you assign a new reference to your `questions` variable. So you end up with the last assignation that you you do, the "difficult" ones. You did not specify what type of object `questions` is, but I would assume it is a `List` or some other `Collection` type. Instead of assigning, try using `Collections.add()` or `Collections.addAll()`.

Comment: List<Question> questions; i must do this ? questions.addAll(questions); in all the IF ?

Comment: what i must please help me i'm a beginner on Java and swing

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Can you help me ?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply, just do questions.addAll(GestionTestDelegate.doPrepareRandomTest(Integer.parseInt(Facile.getText()), categorie,"Facile"); << repeat for all three branches.